# Prevent IE10 from Redirecting to Login Page After 401 Error on AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following javascript code that performs a POST to an API for a login page:

```
        do_post_form_data = function (relative_url, access_token, postData) {
        return $.Deferred(function (def) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: baseURL + relative_url,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postData
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                def.resolve(data);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var error = jqXHR.responseJSON ? jqXHR.responseJSON : { error: "", error_description: "POST failed." };
                def.reject(error);
            });
        });
    },
```

If the login fails (invalid credentials are sent), the API returns a 401 Unauthorized error to the caller with a JSON object in the body explaining why the login failed.  The code works as expected when sending the data from the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  The responseJSON object exists on the jqXHR object, and I can retrieve the error messages.

However, IE10 seems to be intercepting the 401 error and trying to redirect to a login page, for which the API server does not provide a URL, though I cannot see any additional calls being made to the server in Fiddler.  My AJAX call never sees the 401 error but winds up receiving a 404 error with no JSON data in the jqXHR object.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and found a way to make IE report the initial 401 error to the AJAX call?  IE10 with jQuery 2.0.2.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it really redirecting to a different page, not just popping up a login dialog?

Comment: I can only assume it is trying to redirect to a new page that does not exist, which is why I am winding up with a 404 error.  As I said I cannot see any other requests being sent when monitoring via Fiddler.

Comment: assumptions should be tested - what does the F12 dev tools panel on "network" show (start capturing before the ajax call, then stop it once all network traffic is done). Is it actually retrieving a new url after the 401?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the suggestion.  Developer tools detail view on the network tab shows the 401 response coming back with a content type of application/json and a content length of 92.  The content length is correct -- the expected json returned is 92 characters.  The Response Body tab in IE developer tools says "No data to view."  jQuery gets a 404 status passed to the $.ajax error function.  Looks like no actual redirection is taking place, but the status is still being reported as a 404, not a 401, with no access to the JSON response.

Comment: Further update:  The ajax request is a cross-domain request.  The javascript call is being made to an API located on another domain.  I deployed the hosting page to the same domain as the API being called and tested again.  The problem went away, and I received the expected 401 with the json error message in the body as expected.  Looks like a CORS issue in IE10?  Other browsers are handling correctly -- or at least -- as I would expect.

Comment: IE is more picky about CORS than other browsers (there's an XDomainRequest object, for instance) but $.ajax should hide that for you. If you're doing CORS, the most important thing is to make sure that the server has the right content-allowed headers when it's generating its response.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I think you're putting me on the right track here.  Found this article that goes into some depth on the issue:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-from-jquery .  Our API server sets the Access-Control-Allow-* headers when it detects a CORS request, but we're not inserting a header for allowing a content type.  Is there such a header that is required?

Comment: sorry, I meant the access-control-allow information.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The info you provided is helping me enough that I could vote it as a correct answer.  If you want, put it in an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: nah, it's not a real answer, just a pointer in the right direction, I'm fine with keeping it a comment. Thanks though =)